Is it normal for a ceph orch osd rm drain to take so long?
I tried to drain the host by running
sudo ceph orch host drain node-three

But it stuck at removing osd with the below status
node-one@node-one:~$ sudo ceph orch osd rm status
OSD  HOST        STATE     PGS  REPLACE  FORCE  ZAP    DRAIN STARTED AT            
2    node-three  draining    1  False    False  False  2024-04-20 20:30:34.689946 

It's a test set-up and I don't have anything written to the OSD.
Here is my ceph status
node-one@node-one:~$ sudo ceph status
  cluster:
    id:     f5ac585a-fe8e-11ee-9452-79c779548dac
    health: HEALTH_OK
 
  services:
    mon: 2 daemons, quorum node-one,node-two (age 21m)
    mgr: node-two.zphgll(active, since 9h), standbys: node-one.ovegfw
    osd: 3 osds: 3 up (since 42m), 3 in (since 42m); 1 remapped pgs
 
  data:
    pools:   1 pools, 1 pgs
    objects: 2 objects, 577 KiB
    usage:   81 MiB used, 30 GiB / 30 GiB avail
    pgs:     2/6 objects misplaced (33.333%)
             1 active+clean+remapped

Is it normal for an orch osd rm drain to take so long?

With only 3 OSDs and a default crush rule with replicated size 3 there's no target where to drain the OSD to. If this is just a test cluster you could to reduce min_size to 1 and size to 2. But please don't ever do that in production.
